# file not found: /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib for architecture i386

Tags: python, ios, xcode, macos, pycrypto

I am on MAC 10.9 with XCode 4.6.3 and have command line tools installed

I am trying to compile pycrypto-2.1.0 using 
python setup.py build and getting following error

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ld: warning: ignoring file build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/MD2.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/MD2.o
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

locate is giving

```
$ locate libdnsinfo.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
```

These path are also added to PATH.

Following is command and error

---

$ python setup.py  build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
warning: GMP library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Hash.MD2' extension
gcc-4.2 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/ -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/ -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/MD2.o
gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/ -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/ -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/MD2.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash/MD2.so
ld: warning: ignoring file build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/MD2.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/MD2.o
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib for architecture x86_64

### collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: I think you are building it for iPhone simulator . Try to change the target from simulator to iOS device

Comment: @Ernaidu: My intention is to build this for iOS Device and i have not changed it for iPhone. how to change, the target ?

Comment: No dude I am telling you that On top left corner we have device family . There you have to select it

Comment: @EmaiduI am not on the simulator, working on OS shell and building

Comment: The issue is solved after upgrading XCode to 5.0.1

Comment: Ok Congrats @user1661010

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well after upgrading to osx 10.9 while attempting to link in openssl libraries to a simple c application.

The quick solution that worked for me is to link one of the libdnsinfo files into /usr/lib/system

ex:

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue in eclipse
Following worked for me:

**1) Find location of lib**

```
 locate libdnsinfo.dynlib
```

2) **Copy and paste location to**

```
 project > properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > MacOS X C Linker > Libraries > Library Search Path
```

Answer (score 0):

Use libdns_services instead, libdnsinfo.dylib is no more supported by latest sdk.